# Create a data log in Google sheets using App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a history in G-sheets.

This is the script that I am using to move data from 1 sheet to another:

```
function copyRowsWithCopyTo() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Source');

  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('History');

  sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(1, 1));
}
```

Optimally this would happen if one of the cells in the range A5:F5 of my spreadsheet ('Source') changes. I assume that this script should make it happen.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var inputValue = e.value;
  if (
    e.source.getSheetName() == 'Source' &&
    e.range.columnStart == 1 &&
    e.range.columnEnd == 6 &&
    e.range.rowStart >= 5 &&
    e.range.rowEnd <= 5
  )
```

Additionally the rows moved should be appended to the data existing data under the 'History' sheet

```
function append() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // Collect the data
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  const sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange('A5:F5');
  const sourceVals = sourceRange.getValues().flat();

  //Append the data
  const destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName('History');
  destinationSheet.appendRow(sourceVals);
}
```

I really struggle to make the scripts work all together and I believe that the OnEdit() fucntion is wrong. Could you please guide me on how to fix it and combine the three scripts?
FYI, the first and the third scripts work fine independently.

SOLVED:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == 'Source' && range.getRow() >= 5 && range.getRow() <= 5 && range.getColumn() >= 1 && range.getColumn() <= 6) {
    var values = sheet.getRange("A5:F5").getValues()[0];
    var historySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('History');
    historySheet.appendRow(values);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IF statement returns FALSE unless the updated range is specifically A5:F5 but not individual cells which is why the other funcitons are not called, like this:

| Range updated | columnStart | columnEnd | rowStart | rowEnd | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A5:F5 | **1** | **6** | **5** | **5** | TRUE |
| A5 | **1** | **1** | **5** | **5** | FALSE |
| F5 | **6** | **6** | **5** | **5** | FALSE |

It needs to be updated to correctly handle all the scenarios where the changes are made for cells between A5:F5, you can update your code as follows:

```
if (
    e.source.getSheetName() == 'Source' &&
    e.range.columnStart >= 1 &&
    e.range.columnEnd <= 6 &&
    e.range.rowStart >= 5 &&
    e.range.rowEnd <= 5
  )
```

The output changes like this, it is TRUE if any single cell in the range is changed and FALSE if is outside the range:

| Range updated | columnStart | columnEnd | rowStart | rowEnd | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A5:F5 | **1** | **6** | **5** | **5** | TRUE |
| A5 | **1** | **1** | **5** | **5** | TRUE |
| F5 | **6** | **6** | **5** | **5** | TRUE |
| A4 | **6** | **6** | **4** | **4** | FALSE |
| G5 | **7** | **7** | **5** | **5** | FALSE |

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer Bryan. I managed to make it work. The original post is edited with the answer. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @Fabien if Bryan's answer actually worked for you (at least for your initial concern), don't forget to either upvote or mark it as 'best answer'. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved!